# C++ geting -243030403 and \300\371 numbers

Tags: c++, arrays

my input is just normal number and name like "12345", "Joe", but the output got all weird number like -2743443232 and \300\230\340,

```
using namespace std;

struct student{
    int Id;
    string name;
};

void display(student *x){
    int i;
    for( i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<"student id : "<<x->Id<<endl;
        cout<<"student name : "<<x->name<<endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    student stu[5];
    int i;
    for( i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<"enter the student id ";
        cin>>stu[i].Id;
        cout<<"enter the name of student : ";
        cin>>stu[i].name;
    }

    display(&stu[5]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: pass display(stu)

Comment: stu[5] is one past the end of the array. see the linked duplicated question for more information

Comment: `cin>>stu[i].name;` may be part of your problem after you fix `display(&stu[5]);`. Make sure they don't type a first and last name. Remember that if you type a space the part up to the first space goes into the `name` and the rest will be input to the next `Id`

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
display(&stu[5]);
```

causes undefined behavior. Remember that in an array of size `5`, `4` is largest valid index to access the array.

Change it to

```
display(&stu[0]);
```

or simply

```
display(stu);
```

---

Re

> but if I change to `&stu[0]`, it will ouput same id and name 5 time?

the answer is, yes given your posted code. You need to update `display` to

```
void display(student *x){
    int i;
    for( i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout << "student id : " << x[i].Id << endl;
        cout << "student name : " << x[i].name << endl;
    }
}
```

to display the data corresponding to all the elements of the array.

Comment: but if I change to &stu[0], it will ouput same id and name 5 time?

Comment: why use . instead of ->

Comment: @newLearner `x[i]` is not a pointer, so need for `->`. Consult your C++ programming text for details on why it's not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This line `display(&stu[5]);` is causing [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

You are saying that `stu` has a 5th index, which it does not.

When you define an `array` of 5 elements. You only really have an index of `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`.

So instead put, `display(&stu[0])`.